# WinRT interop with real C++

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I have this library written in regular C++ that expects an `std::istream&` that it will read from and block. It compiles just fine under WinRT.

The [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class in .NET beeing fairly similar, I figured it would be an easy task. To make the library read from one of those.

However, in WinRT there is only an [async stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp) available. It is easy to convert my Stream object into a `IInputStream`. But how do I wrap it in order to be able to pass it to the library expecting an `std::istream&`?

```
void readFrom(std::istream& input);
```

Comment: The elegant way to do so would be to create a WinRT Component DLL using C++/CX and using it to pass an `std::istream &`. However, getting it back would be tricky (`Platform::IntPtr` is the probably the only way of pushing native pointers across the ABI boundary, and it's not that supported a method).

Comment: this code is already in a WinRT Component DLL using C++/CX. I've done some research and I think I just need to extend std::streambuf and in the underflow member function just read from the stream using a WinRT DataReader...

Comment: If you have a solution, could you post an answer to your question?

Comment: I have no clue, hence the question.

Comment: Your last comment from Apr 24 13 indicating you had done some research and had an approach you were going to try. Since it has been 5 years, I figured you either had a solution or you abandoned this.

Comment: Yeah, I abandoned it. But I think the comment is basically what I found out. Today, there might be some easier way.